# C# datagramsocket cannot receive

Tags: c#, udp

I'm trying to make datagramsocket on UWP connect to UDPClient on desktop.

The odd thing is that datagramsocket never receive any message from UDPClient(event not work) unless send out message to UDPClient from datagramsocket first.

On the other hand, i'm sure my config(IP/PORT setting) is OK, because same config on UDPClients works OK.

Is there anything wrong with my code?(UWP CODE:)

```
private async void btn_start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//Listen
{
    hostname = new HostName("192.168.1.5");
    remotename = new HostName("192.168.1.5");

    datagramsocket = new DatagramSocket();

    datagramsocket.MessageReceived += Datagramsocket_MessageReceived;

    try
    {
        await datagramsocket.BindServiceNameAsync("8010");

        await datagramsocket.ConnectAsync(remotename, "8009");
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        //show err message method
    }
}

private async void Datagramsocket_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{//read from args
    //it works after click send button
}

//if i don't click btn_send first, then the MessageReceived event will never work
private async void btn_send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//send
{
    string str_send = tb_send.Text;
    byte[] str_byte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str_send);

    IOutputStream outputstream = await datagramsocket.GetOutputStreamAsync(remotename, "8009");

    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputstream);
    writer.WriteBytes(str_byte); 
    await writer.StoreAsync();
}
```